Insulated ceiling for house with earth filled walls made of CGI and reinforcing bars
There are lot of people on the Internet trying to build a cheap and sustainable house. Inspired by them I came with the idea of building external walls of Corrugated galvanised iron (CGI) and rebars and fill them with earth / sand. The basic element of the wall structure is this rebar trapeze with hooks on the inner side:

The height of the trapeze is 3 meter, the base - 1m and the top 0.5m. Both its legs are placed fully into the ground up to the horizontal bottom bar (base). Many such trapezes are placed at the perimeter of the future house and welded together into the following structure:


Next CGI sheets are perforated and hanged on both sides of the trapezes (on the inner hooks) starting from the bottom. Once they are filled with earth, next level of CGI sheets is added upon the lower level and also filled. During the filling, once the earth reaches their level - opposite hooks can be connected with metal wire to reduce chances of trapeze deformation. And so on until everything is filled up. Inner space can be divided into rooms using metal rods and drywall (gypsum panels). Ceiling and the roof will be supported by a separate metal rods structure of appropriate size. Some of those metal rods might be buried inside the earth of the walls.
I assume that the thermal mass of the earth will be enough to keep such a house (10mx20m) cool in summers (with temperatures around 32-36C) and warm in winters without air conditioning. Provided the ceiling / roof are well thermally insulated. What kind of ceiling would you recommend in that case? The material should provide good thermal insulation (preferably also acoustic, be inflammable and not cause health problems).
